# Manipulating bash script output using variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am new to scripting using Linux. When running a script I want to be selective about what output the script show from a command, instead of displaying all of a commands output, I would like for it to display some of its words or sentences. How do I do that. Help will be appreciated. See below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

megacliout=$(sudo megacli -AdpAutoRbld -Dsply -a0)

echo $megacliout | cut -d '0' -f 2
```

The output I get is:

```
: AutoRebuild is Enabled. Exit Code:
```

But I do not want 'Exit Code:' to be displayed in the output. So how do I remove that and keep everything else?

Comment: Show the output of `sudo megacli -AdpAutoRbld -Dsply -a0`

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely better answered at SuperUser.

That said, your `cut` command is unlikely to work reliably. You are using it to extract text between two zeroes (which might or might not be present in the output).

As an alternative, you can try `grep`, for example like so: `grep -o 'AutoRebuild is [^.]*'`
This will output only phrases that start with "AutoRebuild is", continuing until the next dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove 'Exit Code' and everything after it with `sed`:

```
echo "$megacliout" | cut -d0 -f2 | sed 's/ Exit Code.*$//'
```

Comment: But then you might as well drop the `cut` entirely and refactor that too into the `sed` script.

Comment: Also, you should properly double-quote the stuff you `echo`, especially if it might contain shell metacharacters.

Comment: @tripleee yes! I added the double-quotes. To replace `cut` with `sed`, I would need the output of `sudo megacli -AdpAutoRbld -Dsply -a0`.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that `s/^[^0]*0:\([^0]*\) Exit code.*/\1/` could solve both problems in one go.  But yeah, the OP should show his input if he wants help manipulating it.